# AS3 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Baddie

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision, compile-time-constant

I'm having issues with a program I've been working on

```
function checkForHit(baddie:Baddie):void
{
for (var i:int = 0; i < bullets.length; i++)
{
    if (baddie.hitTestPoint(bullets[i].x,bullets[i].y,true))
    {
        removeChild(baddie);
        removeChild(bullets[i]);
        baddies.splice(baddies.indexOf(baddie), 1);
        bullets.splice(bullets[i]);
        updateScore(100);
        killCounter +=  1;
        checkKillCounter();
    }
}
}
```

I get Level 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 165   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Baddie.

I can figure out why. I tried declaring it but that didn't seem to work

Also, it seems to work in another program that a friend did, his seemed to work fine

Comment: I guess you have to import that Baddie class. "import myPackage.Baddie"

Comment: No change, same error. any other ideas?

Comment: include right library path in flash ide settings and ofcourse i belive u change myPackge to correct package :D